# XML - Edit vector image

Tags: android, xml, vector

I want to edit this XML vector image. How can I remove the middle lines from the image?

```
    <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24"
        android:viewportHeight="24"
        android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal">
        <path
            android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
            android:pathData="M7,15h7v2L7,17zM7,11h10v2L7,13zM7,7h10v2L7,9zM19,3h-4.18C14.4,1.84 13.3,1 12,1c-1.3,0 -2.4,0.84 -2.82,2L5,3c-0.14,0 -0.27,0.01 -0.4,0.04 -0.39,0.08 -0.74,0.28 -1.01,0.55 -0.18,0.18 -0.33,0.4 -0.43,0.64 -0.1,0.23 -0.16,0.49 -0.16,0.77v14c0,0.27 0.06,0.54 0.16,0.78s0.25,0.45 0.43,0.64c0.27,0.27 0.62,0.47 1.01,0.55 0.13,0.02 0.26,0.03 0.4,0.03h14c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2L21,5c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2zM12,2.75c0.41,0 0.75,0.34 0.75,0.75s-0.34,0.75 -0.75,0.75 -0.75,-0.34 -0.75,-0.75 0.34,-0.75 0.75,-0.75zM19,19L5,19L5,5h14v14z"/>
    </vector>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your variant with this:

```
android:pathData="M19,3h-4.18C14.4,1.84 13.3,1 12,1c-1.3,0 -2.4,0.84 -2.82,2L5,3c-0.14,0 -0.27,0.01 -0.4,0.04 -0.39,0.08 -0.74,0.28 -1.01,0.55 -0.18,0.18 -0.33,0.4 -0.43,0.64 -0.1,0.23 -0.16,0.49 -0.16,0.77v14c0,0.27 0.06,0.54 0.16,0.78s0.25,0.45 0.43,0.64c0.27,0.27 0.62,0.47 1.01,0.55 0.13,0.02 0.26,0.03 0.4,0.03h14c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2L21,5c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2zM12,2.75c0.41,0 0.75,0.34 0.75,0.75s-0.34,0.75 -0.75,0.75 -0.75,-0.34 -0.75,-0.75 0.34,-0.75 0.75,-0.75zM19,19L5,19L5,5h14v14z"
```

Comment: It's working, but can you tell me how can I program my own path data? Please attach some source.

Comment: I don't know any visual tool, however you can learn how path data's segments are parsing and what is what in it via SVG specification. Here is the reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html. I hope it will help you.